# Bash: Calling bash script from postgresql trigger function

Tags: bash, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am calling a bash script from the trigger function in postgresql. The script is called after update of the value(log_interval) in the table in SQL.

The read the changed value(log_interval) from the table in the script that is called and store in a file (interval.txt). If I open the file I see the old value of log_interval and not the new value in the interval.txt file.

Below is the code snippet that I am using:

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_upload_interval()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
exec /home/User/ReadInterval.sh &
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh VOLATILE
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER assign_new_interval
AFTER UPDATE OF log_interval
ON table_interval
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ((old.log_interval IS DISTINCT FROM new.log_interval))
EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_upload_interval();
```

Script code:

```
function readinterval() {
logperiod=$(psql -c "select log_interval from table_interval where id=1;" -t  $database_name)
echo "$logperiod" > /home/User/interval.txt
}
```

Am new to scripting and using SQL. Let me know the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's usually a pretty bad idea to use PL/SH and invoke shell scripts from the server. Wherever possible use `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` to get a helper daemon to do the work instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there's more code that isn't being shown here, just calling `ReadInterval.sh` won't do anything because it's nothing but a function declaration. In addition, there's a variable `$database_name` that isn't being set.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_upload_interval()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
#!/bin/sh
database_name=???
psql -c "select log_interval from table_interval where id=1;" -t  $database_name > /home/User/interval.txt
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plsh VOLATILE
```

Comment: Probably I'm talking to the void here, but this does seem like a valid question that can't just be closed off. Why it garnered three upvotes is beyond me though.